# domain expiration during transfer

Tags: domains, domain-registrar, transfer

What happens to domain expiration during transfer to a *different* registrar?

Currently my domain will expire in 2012. I wonder if it will be affected in any way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expiration date should be unaffected. However, many registrars require you to add another year to your registration when you transfer over to their services. But it will never expire sooner than its current expiration date.

Comment: *than not then, SE doesn't let me edit 1 char :)

Comment: @m33lky corrected :)

Comment: Also, many registrars will not allow you to initiate a domain transfer if it's close to expiring - they will require that you add an extra year before you transfer out to ensure that it doesn't expire during the process, this is because for some domains the current registrar needs to say "this domain can be moved" and then the second registrar has up to a month to say "yes, hand it over".